# How to change the name of a variable in a function within a selection?

Tags: replace

I want to use Ctrl-space at the start of a function, and at the end of a function to select the area of the function and then change the name of a variable `var1` to `var2`. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have marked the region, you can run `M-%` which is `query-replace`.

In your mode line (the status bar at the bottom) it will ask you to type in the name of the variable you want to change. Afterwards press enter and it will ask you what you want to change it to.

At this point it has highlighted the instances of your original variable and the cursor will be at the first one. You can press `space` and it will replace that instance, or press `del` to skip to the next one.

If you want to replace them all without checking individually you can press `!`

If you want to do something more complex, you can use `C-M-%` which will let you use `query-replace` with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `C-M-SPC` at the start of a function to mark the entire thing. `C-M-a` moves to the beginning of a function quickly.

Then, `M-%` to run `query-replace` on the region. Type `var1 RET var2 RET` then `y`/`n` to choose whether to replace each occurrence or `!` to replace them all.

You may also want to use `C-h r` to read the Emacs manual.

Comment: the `M-%` works great. I can't get the C-M-SPC to work to select the fn automatically (python context)

Comment: It works for me in Python. It should be bound to the command `mark-sexp` (hit `C-h c C-M-SPC` to check). Your cursor needs to be on the `d` in `def`.